# How do we vary the Einstein-Hilbert Action?

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, general-relativity, gauge-theory

The Einstein-Hilbert actions is:
$$
\begin{align}
   S=\int_M R(g)\text{dvol}_g=\int_M\sqrt{-g}Rd^4x
\end{align}
$$
I'm looking to vary the action in a coordinate free way without appealing to the Euler-Lagrange equations. For example, in Yang-Mills theory, we fix a principal bundle $P$ over a Pseudo-Riemannian manifold $M$, with compact structure group $G$. Then, with an ad-invariant inner product on $\mathfrak{g}$, we get an induced bundle metric on $\text{Ad}(P)$, the vector bundle associated to $P$ with fibre $V=\mathfrak{g}$, and the representation the adjoint representation. Then we write the action:
$$
\begin{align}
S[A]=\int_M\langle F_M^A,F_M^A \rangle_{\text{Ad}(P)}\text{dvol}_g
\end{align}
$$
Where $F_M^A\in \Omega^2(M,\text{Ad}(P))$, is the curvature two form corresponding to $A$. Since the set of connections is an affine space over $\Omega^1(M,\text{Ad}(P))$, we are able to define critical points as those that satisfy:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}S[A+t\alpha_m]=0
\end{align}
$$
for all $\alpha_M\in \Omega(M,\text{Ad}(P))$. So how do we do something similar for the Einstein Hilbert action? I am mainly confused because I don't think the set of pseudo riemannian metrics on some manifold is an affine space in anyway. Is there any less physicsy text that treats GR this way? i.e. not appealing to some calculation in coordinates?

Comment: No, the set of pseudo-Riemannian metrics is not an affine space, however, it is open in the space of symmetric $(0,2)$ tensor fields, atleast in the sense that if $g$ is Lorentzian, then for any compactly supported (perhaps we can get rid of compact support here; I don’t remember off hand if it’s relevant) symmetric $(0,2)$ tensor field $h$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $|t|<\delta$, the tensor field $g+th$ is still Lorentzian. With this openness condition, calculating the derivative $\frac{d}{dt}\big\rvert_{t=0}S[g+th]$ is possible.

Comment: However, I’m not sure how this would simplify the computations in any way. To clarify, I mentioned (since that’s in the body of your post) how to make sense of the derivative, but not your title question of how to calculate it coordinate-free (I’ve never seen it done, but then again I haven’t looked/thought hard enough).

Comment: I care less about simplicity and more about doing things in a way that doesn’t use coordinates

Comment: I assume $h$ needs to be the same signature right?

Comment: $h$ can be any symmetric tensor. The point is that $t$ is small, which is why $g+th$ is still Lorentzian.

Comment: [My notes](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/time_ev.pdf) seem to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @IvoTerek Is it ok if I email you with some questions about your notes? You are correct this is exactly what I was looking for, there are just some small things I don't quite get.

Comment: @Chris Yes, no problem.